# How do I sort a character matrix according to a sorted number matrix?

Tags: r

I have a matrix of Student's `grades`.

```
         Winston  Ariana  James
Math          50      70     90
Science       85      90     50
Biology       40      30     80
```

How do I turn that matrix into a sorted matrix of students' top performing lessons?

```
Winston   Ariana   James
Science   Science  Math 
Math      Math     Biology
Biology   Biology  Science
```

I have the idea of sorting the `grades` matrix using `apply(grades, 2, sort, decreasing=TRUE)` and then creating a matrix (let's call it `temp`) like so: `matrix(rownames(grades), nrow=nrow(grades), ncol=ncol(grades), dimnames=list(c(NULL), c(colnames(grades))))` in which every row of the temp matrix is going to be filled by the rownames of grades. And then somehow pass the value of `grades` to `temp`, and then I sort it.

Can anyone help solve this problem in a better way or let me know how do I pass the value of `grades` to `temp` without changing the elements of `temp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We turn the `matrix` to `data.frame`, create the rownames as a column (`rownames_to_column`), `mutate` the columns except the first, by `order` the values in decreasing order and then use that to index to rearrange the rownames in each column, convert the 'rn' column back to rownames and change it to `matrix` again

```
library(tidyverse)
m1 %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
  mutate_at(-1, list(~ rn[order(., decreasing = TRUE)])) %>%
  column_to_rownames('rn') %>%
  as.matrix
#     Winston   Ariana    James    
#Math    "Science" "Science" "Math"   
#Science "Math"    "Math"    "Biology"
#Biology "Biology" "Biology" "Science"
```

---

Or we can `melt` into 'long' format, do the `arrange` in the 'long' form, and do a `spread`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(m1) %>%
   arrange(Var2, desc(value)) %>% 
   group_by(Var2) %>%      
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   dplyr::select(-value) %>% 
   spread(Var2, Var1)
```

---

Or using `base R`, loop through the column of `matrix`, `order` the column values in decreasing order, use the index to order the rownames as in above

```
apply(m1, 2, function(x) row.names(m1)[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)])
#    Winston   Ariana    James    
#[1,] "Science" "Science" "Math"   
#[2,] "Math"    "Math"    "Biology"
#[3,] "Biology" "Biology" "Science"
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(50L, 85L, 40L, 70L, 90L, 30L, 90L, 50L, 80L), .Dim = c(3L, 
 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("Math", "Science", "Biology"),
  c("Winston", "Ariana", "James")))
```